# Copy-Item from New-PSDrive within PSSession

Tags: powershell, copy-item

I have the following Powershell code:

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName test01 
New-PSDrive -Name Source -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\test02\SMBTest -Credential test\Administrator 
Copy-Item Source:\Test.txt -Destination C:\Temp
Remove-PSDrive Source 
Exit-PSSession
```

When I execute each line on it's own it works, but when I save it and run it as a ps1 file it doesn't do anything.

Can anyone help explain why (I'm using Powershell --version 5.1)

Comment: Why are you entering a session in a script?  Utilize `Invoke-Command`.  Although I think you're running into a third-hop problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks @theincorrigible1 - I've modified it to the below and it is now working.

```
$s = New-PSSession -ComputerName test01
Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock {
New-PSDrive -Name Source -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\test02\SMBTest -
Credential test\Administrator
Copy-Item Source:\Test.txt -Destination C:\Temp
Remove-PSDrive Source
}
```